# Is it possible for SYN/ACK to not be immediately proceeded by a SYN in a network trace

Tags: tcp, wireshark

I'm writing a simple program to calculate initial RTTs from a network capture I took using Wireshark. To do this I wan't to calculate the difference in time between the SYN and the SYN/ACK. I don't know much about locating these in my trace, I was gonna parse for SYNs that immediately have SYN/ACKs in the next line. But **I was wondering if its possible that other TCP data could be on the next line thus ruining my plan? If so how do I find the corresponding SYN/ACK to a SYN?**
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I think other TCP data could be on the next line. For example:

- If the network device opens two concurrent connections, the line that follows the SYN may show a TCP packet from the other stream.
- If a congested router in the network path drops the initial SYN packet, the capture file may present two or more consecutive SYN packets related to the same connection.

I suggest the following algorithm:

1. Find a TCP packet `P2` whose SYN and ACK flags are set. `P2.ack`, `P2.dst` and `P2.src` will be the acknowledge number, destination port and source port, respectively.
2. Search backwards a TCP packet `P1`, whose:

   2.1. Source port matches `P2.dst` AND

   2.2. Destination port matches `P2.src` AND

   2.3. Sequence number matches `P2.ack - 1` AND

   2.4. SYN flag is set AND

   2.5. ACK flag is not set
3. RTT will be the time between the packets `P1` and `P2`.

Consider comparing IP header data also. The `P1`'s source address must match `P2`'s destination address and *vice versa*.

References: 
[TCP segment structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_segment_structure) ; [Connection establishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment)